# Conditions that the minimal polynomial splits

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials, invariance

Suppose there is a linear transform T from V to V where V is the finite dimensional vector space, what will be the conditions that the minimal polynomial splits? 
I know if it splits then T is diagonalizable and all the T-invariant subspaces will have an eigenvector of T, will these implies the minimal polynomial splits?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That depends over what field you're working with. For example, the minimal polynomial of a matrix in $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb C)$ is always reducible, unlike the minimal polynomial of a matrix in $M_{2\times 2} (\mathbb R)$. Note that the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial have the same irreducible parts.

Comment: "If it splits then $T$ is diagonalisable". Surely not? "If it is a product of DISTINCT linear factors then $T$ is diagonalisable, and vice versa" is the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the minimal polynomial$~\mu_T$ is split if and only if the characteristic polynomial$~\chi_T$ is split, as both have the same irreducible factors (since $\mu_T$ divides $\chi_T$, which divides a power of$~\mu_T$). If none of these irreducible factors have degree${}\geq2$ then $\mu_T$ and $\chi_T$ are split, otherwise they are not.

Clearly this condition depends on the field one is working over. Over an algebraically closed field like $\Bbb C$ all irreducible polynomials are of degree$~1$, so $\mu_T$ and $\chi_T$ are always split. Working over other fields$~K$ they are not always split.

If $\mu_T$ has an irreducible factor$~P\in K[X]$ with $\deg P>1$ (so in particular $P$ has no roots in$~K$) then $\ker(P[T]$) is a nonzero $T$-stable subspace without any eigenvectors of$~T$. So indeed, if there are no such subspaces, that implies that $\mu_T$ and $\chi_T$ were split. Conversely, if $\mu_T$ splits, then $V$ is a direct sum of generalised eigenspaces of$~T$, and the projections on the factors of this decomposition are given by certain polynomials in$~T$; this implies that any $T$-stable subspace contains its own projections on the generalised eigenspaces, and is the direct sum of those projections. Moreover any nonzero $T$-stable subspace of a generalised eigenspace for$~\lambda$ contains an eigenvector for$~\lambda$, so by the preceding any nonzero $T$-stable subspace of$~V$ contains an eigenvector.

So indeed this property characterises $T$ with split $\mu_T$.

Comment: When you say "then  ker(P[T]) is a non zero T stable subspace without any eigenvector" do you mean without any eigenvector of P[T]? It seems it doesn't hold if that's the eigenvector of T?

Comment: No of course not: $P[T]$ by definition acts as $0$ on its own kernel, so any nonzero vector in that subspace is eigenvector of $P[T]$. But such a vector cannot be eigenvector of$~T$, because the corresponding eigenvalue would have to be a root of $P$, which does not exist. (I'm using that on an eigenvector of$~T$ for$~\lambda$, a polynomial $Q[T]$ in$~T$ acts as the scalar$~Q[\lambda]$.)

Comment: Got you, thank you so much